# Proton Orion Subscription - Error when parsing notification XML

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I had configured Orion and Proton FIWARE Generic Enablers and made a subscription in Orion to send a notification to Proton when an entity of type Node is modified.

It happens that Proton is returning an error related with the parsing of the received XML.

```
proton | Mar 02, 2016 11:46:47 AM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventXmlNgsiMessageReader readFrom
proton | INFO: started event message body reader
proton | Mar 02, 2016 11:46:47 AM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventXmlNgsiMessageReader readFrom
proton | INFO: Event: NodeContextUpdate
proton | Mar 02, 2016 11:46:47 AM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventXmlNgsiMessageReader readFrom
proton | SEVERE: Could not parse XML NGSI event java.lang.NullPointerException, reason: null
proton |  last attribute name: null last value: null
```

I found that at least another user had posted a similar question but the answer to that question does not fits (and solve) my situation.

EDIT:

Here is the POST request that Proton has received:

```
........POST /ProtonOnWebServer/rest/events HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: orion/0.27.0-next libcurl/7.19.7
Host: 192.168.99.100:8080
Accept: application/xml, application/json
Content-length: 901
Content-type: application/xml

<notifyContextRequest>
  <subscriptionId>570b7cad849a7fd6c9ebaaf3</subscriptionId>
  <originator>localhost</originator>
  <contextResponseList>
    <contextElementResponse>
      <contextElement>
        <entityId type="Node" isPattern="false">
          <id>Node3</id>
        </entityId>
        <contextAttributeList>
          <contextAttribute>
            <name>temperature</name>
            <type>double</type>
            <contextValue>23</contextValue>
          </contextAttribute>
          <contextAttribute>
            <name>pressure</name>
            <type>double</type>
            <contextValue>15</contextValue>
          </contextAttribute>
        </contextAttributeList>
      </contextElement>
      <statusCode>
        <code>200</code>
        <reasonPhrase>OK</reasonPhrase>
      </statusCode>
    </contextElementResponse>
  </contextResponseList>
</notifyContextRequest>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of others who look this thread up, here is Jose's explanation to his resolution of this problem. I hope Jose is ok with that:

> The first time I've run into an similar error, I was not making the
>   subscription in Orion to send the information in XML format. The
>   solution was to use "Accept":"application/xml" it the header of the
>   subscription POST resquest in order to Orion to notify Proton in XML
>   NGSI. (The reason XML should be used is because the JSON format
>   accepted by Proton is not NGSI).
>
> This time I was just forgetting to put entityType attribute in the
>   NodeContextUpdate event definition.